# 4500X performance question

Tags: cisco

i have a pair of 4500x in VSS with 950x SVI and 6x BGP peers with no full tables (there is no other configs) now i want to configure 4-5x GRE tunnel and and 1-2x gre tunnel will have around 500mbps traffic and left of them are backup gre and i may apply pbr and tcp mss adjust for some interface, so i want to know can i safely run these features or they impact so much on my switch performance?
also does 4500x support IP tcp mss adjust ?
thanks,

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

PBR is supported in hardware on the 4500X so long as your policy routes fit within the available TCAM.

GRE is supported in hardware.

I believe TCP MSS Adjust is supported as well.

Comment: so all of them are supported in hardware? do you know if tcp mss supported in hardware or not ? thus when pbr and gre supported in hardware i should except no performance issue right?

Comment: I think TCP MSS Adjust is in hardware but a quick search didn't turn up any solid information one way or the other.